# Grub has two time the same kernels in menu

Tags: 12.04, boot, grub2, kernel, dual-boot

After update (yesterday) from Ubuntu 12.04, GRUB has two of the same kernels in the boot menu for Ubuntu 12.04 (I have triple boot). I have already reinstalled GRUB, but with the same result. It seems to me that something is going wrong in `update-grub`:

```
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-24-generic-pae
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-24-generic-pae
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-24-generic-pae
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-24-generic-pae
Found Windows Vista (loader) on /dev/sda2
Found Ubuntu 11.04 (11.04) on /dev/sda7
done
```

There is no problem for boot but this is not nice. Solution?

Comment: Please provide the output of sudo fdisk -l

Comment: `dpkg --list | grep linux-image-generic` please

Comment: Use step 5:  http://tuxtweaks.com/2010/10/remove-old-kernels-in-ubuntu-with-one-command/  don't forget to run sudo update-grub

Comment: dpkg --list | grep linux-image-generic  give as result: 
ii  linux-image-generic-pae                3.2.0.24.26                                         Generic Linux kernel image

Comment: /dev/sda1      63    16787924     8393931   27  Hidden NTFS WinRE
/dev/sda2   *  16787928   141916159    62564116    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       141916160   299204607    78644224    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       299206654   781402111   241097729    5  uitgebreid
/dev/sda5   388919296   697753599   154417152    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6       760293376   781402111    10554368    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda7   299206656   383795199    42294272   83  Linux
/dev/sda8       383797248   388917247     2560000   82  Linux swap
/dev/sda9    97755648   760291327    31267840   83  Linux

Comment: @shantanu: the kernel is the same (twice), not a old kernel

Comment: Can you please provide the output of `ls -l / /boot/ | grep vmlinuz`?

Comment: ls -l / /boot/ | grep vmlinuz  result in : 

lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    33 apr 29 10:56 vmlinuz -> boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-24-generic-pae
     
-rw------- 1 root root  5017056 mei 22 01:50 vmlinuz-3.2.0-24-generic-pae

Comment: @JulienChau you have two linux disk (sda7 and sda9). Did you install two linux os?

Comment: @ shantanu: i have triple boot: ubuntu 12.04; ubuntu 11.10 and vista. But ubuntu 11.10 has another kernel and is correctly in the menu.

Comment: Sorry, it is 11.04, and the kernel for 11.04 is 2.6.38-15.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the reason why. Sometime ago I made some changes to the file /etc/grubd.d/10_linux .  For security reasons I made a copy of this file (.bak).   This file was still executable.  It has never caused problems till the last update of the system.  The only thing I had to do was a chmod so this file  (.bak) so he was no longer executable.  By doing sudo update-grub all the files that are present in the /etc/grub.d and are executable are taken in the grub.cfg  file, what caused the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, I think you're suppose to use: update-grub2

Try to see if this is the fix. It's working for me just fine on old Maverick.

Comment: `update-grub2` is actually a symbolic link to the `update-grub` script in `/usr/sbin/`

Comment: that is correct update-grub is OK.  But update-grub does not fix the problem.(see my question).  It is not a old kernel - it is the latest kernel.

Comment: @JulienChau yes, my actual intention was to inform that you have already tried that.

Comment: I did understand this Samik - my answer was in the first place to Frese